# Google compute engine unable to delete

Tags: google-compute-engine

i've been having an issue for a few days now. I have a VM instance that i want gone. now this machine comes back after a few minutes regardless of what i change. If i stop it, it starts again.
If i delete it, after a few minutes its back and running.

[image]

How on earth am i supposed to delete a VM ? is there a sequence that i am not following ?

Answer (score 1):

That would be an [expected behavior](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#managed_instance_groups) if your instance is a part of Managed Instance Group.

> If an instance in the group stops, crashes, or is deleted by an action other than the instance groups commands, the managed instance group automatically recreates the instance so it can resume its processing tasks.